# Exercise on measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, definition

I have this exercise:

> Let $\mathscr {S}$ be a collection of subsets of the set $X$. Show that for each $A$ in $\sigma(\mathscr S)$ there is a countable subfamily $\mathscr C_0$ of $\mathscr S$ such that $A\in\sigma(\mathscr C_0)$. $($Hint: Let $\mathscr A$ be the union of the $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(\mathscr C)$, where $\mathscr C$ ranges over the countable subfamilies of $\mathscr S$, and show that $\mathscr A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that satisfies $\mathscr S\subset\mathscr A\subset \sigma(\mathscr S)$.$)$

from the book "Measure theory - *Donald L. Cohn*"

I don't know what $\sigma(...)$ is? Thank you.

Comment: $\sigma(\mathcal C)$ is the [$\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra). That is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal C$. That is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras  containing $\mathcal C$.

Comment: As the book surely explains.

Comment: If the definition is not in the book, throw it away and get another book.

Comment: ok thank you , and to solve this exercise what is the idea ? please

Comment: @julien i must work with this book there a proof about measurable projection theorem

Comment: So, couldn't you find the definition of $\sigma(C)$ in the book?

Comment: The definition is on the bottom of page 3 in the 1994 edition.

Comment: For the exercise itself, the hint is very explicit, no? Once you have shown the hint, not that it actually says $\sigma(\mathcal S)=\mathcal A$. So any element of $\sigma(S$ belongs to this $\mathcal A$, which is a union. So there exists an element of the union which contains your element. And this says exactly what you are after.

Comment: i use the hint in order to solve the exercise ?

Comment: Try using the hint to solve the exercise, yes!  As far as I know, whenever Cohn says "Hint" it really is helpful, it is not a red herring.